# objective-c json serialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, request, http-post

I need to create a POST request and in it's body I need to put a JSON. The template for the JSON file is as follows:

```
{"key" : [{...}, {...}, {...} ..... ]}
```

What I've tried doing is something like this:

```
@{@"key" : @[@{...}, @{...} ... ]};
```

The issue I have is that it puts round brackets around the `NSArray`.
This is the output:

```
{key = ({...}, {...}, ..... )}
```

Snippet from my code(after I've created the `NSDictionary`)

```
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myDictionary
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                         error:&error];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
```

Is there a way for me to make the `NSArray` have `[ ]` instead of `( )`?

Comment: you can create a NSString and append each protion of the to be json strings to get that. ie.  

`NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"key\" : [{%@}, {%@}, {%@}]}",stringPart1,stringPart2,stringPart3];`

Comment: Is the snippet from NSLog or from a string version of the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSLog uses {} for printing NSDictionary and () for printing NSArray contents. This has nothing to do with JSON. Your JSON data structure is created and encoded correctly. To verify do this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

And you will see that the actual JSON is printed.